# Update data based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table and want to update a column based on other column of same table. Please look at below image for table design and table data.

[image]

In this tbl I want to update JoinDate as below steps.

1)  if ModifiedDatetime is not null then ModifiedDatetime  else CreatedDate.

2) Now if NextLevel is Hour then want to add hour of above date which we have in setp 1

3) Now if NextLevel is Day then want to add Day of above date which we have in setp 1

4) Now if NextLevel is Min then want to add Min of above date which we have in setp 1

5) Finally after completing all above process the date which I will get , I want to use to that data to update joindate.

I did this usig below cursor but I wnat to do this using sql update query.

```
DECLARE @EmpID INT
Declare @DtTm datetime
DECLARE @NextLevl INT
Declare @JoinDtTm datetime

DECLARE CurProg CURSOR FOR 
select EmpID from tblEmp 

OPEN CurProg
FETCH NEXT
FROM CurProg INTO @EmpID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
select @DtTm = case when ModifiedTime is null then CreatedDate else ModifiedTime end, @NextLevl = NextLevel  from tblEmp where EmpID = @EmpID
if (@NextLevl = 'Min')
BEGIN
   set @JoinDtTm = DATEADD(MI,1,@DtTm)
END
ELSE IF (@NextLevl= 'Hour')
BEGIN
   set @JoinDtTm = DATEADD(HH,1,@DtTm)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   set @JoinDtTm = DATEADD(D,1,@DtTm)
END
--update tblEmp set JoinDtTm = @JoinDtTm where EMPId= @EMPId


FETCH NEXT
FROM CurProg INTO @EmpID
END
CLOSE CurProg
DEALLOCATE CurProg
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Comment: So this is your requirement. Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes I did this using CURSOR but I want to compelte this without cursor.

Comment: Post your code using the Cursor... If nothing else, it'll help clarify your question.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question in which I add my CURSOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET JoinDate = CASE WHEN NextLevel = 'Hour' THEN DATEADD(HH,1,ISNULL(ModifiedDate,CreatedDate))
                    WHEN NextLevel = 'Day' THEN DATEADD(DD,1,ISNULL(ModifiedDate,CreatedDate))
                    WHEN NextLevel = 'Min' THEN DATEADD(MI,1,ISNULL(ModifiedDate,CreatedDate))
                END
```

Comment: how would you handle future inserts with this ? Run the update every day, every hour, every 10 minutes. Maybe use a trigger ? Although this answers the question, it is not a good method.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk for future insert, in WHERE clause we can have condition
UPDATE ... ... WHERE JoinDate IS NULL.

Comment: @NithinGangadharan so every time you insert, you also do an update. Don't you see a problem with that ? Your column should be COMPUTED maybe also PERSISTED if needed

Comment: @t-clausen.dk If you look at the requirement, in that poster has mentioned ModifiedDate to be considered first. That means there can be few operation done after you insert the values. COMPUTED column may not be useful as the JoinDate is calculated only once, here it will create unnecessary overhead to calculate this value every time you execute the query. And also can't use PERSISTED too because as I mentioned the JoinDate may be calculated after performing few steps, hence the ModifiedDate is updated and PERSISTED field will generate and store the value as soon as values are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without a cursor in an update statement then this should work

```
    UPDATE TBL_EMP
SET JOINDATE =
(CASE WHEN MODIFIEDTIME IS NOT NULL 
THEN (CASE WHEN NEXTLEVEL ='Hour' THEN dateadd(hh,1,modifiedtime) 
ELSE (CASE WHEN NEXTLEVEL = 'Day'  THEN dateadd(dd,1,MODIFIEDTIME)  
ELSE(CASE WHEN NEXTLEVEL = 'Min'  THEN dateadd(n,1,MODIFIEDTIME)  ELSE MODIFIEDTIME END) END) END)
ELSE(CASE WHEN NEXTLEVEL ='Hour' THEN dateadd(hh,1,CREATEDDATE)  
ELSE(CASE WHEN NEXTLEVEL = 'Day' THEN dateadd(dd,1,CREATEDDATE) 
ELSE(CASE WHEN NEXTLEVEL = 'Min'   THEN dateadd(n,1,CREATEDDATE)  ELSE CREATEDDATE END) END) END) END)
FROM TBL_EMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop your column joindate, it is redundant. Since joindate always rely on other columns in the same row, all you need is a computed column like this, otherwise you are stuck on constantly maintaining the values in joindate:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD cJoindate as
  CASE NextLevel 
    WHEN 'day' THEN DATEADD(D, 1, COALESCE(ModifiedDate,CreatedDate))
    WHEN 'min' THEN DATEADD(MI, 1, COALESCE(ModifiedDate,CreatedDate))
    WHEN 'hour' THEN DATEADD(HH, 1, COALESCE(ModifiedDate,CreatedDate))
  END
```